# OAuth2 flow in web frontend and REST API

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, oauth-2.0

I'm working on a project based on [Phalcon](https://phalconphp.com/it/) which consists in two different stand-alone subprojects: a **php + angular frontend** and a **php REST API**.

I protected the API with OAuth2, using [PhpLeague OAuth2 Server](https://oauth2.thephpleague.com/). The *API* server is the OAuth2's *authorization* server AND *resource* server.

This is the actual flow:

1. The user can browse the public endpoints of the frontend, and when hits a private page, gets redirected to the login page;
2. The login page has username and password, POSTs them to the *frontend* server;
3. The *frontend* server calls a public method on the *API* server, which is expecting a Password Credential Grant: it validates the credentials and sends back an access token and a refresh token;
4. The *frontend* server caches both the access and refresh token in session and uses it for some API calls: the first of those is the '/users/me', which gets info about the current user and its ACL on the frontend sections;
5. The *frontend* server sends the page to the browser, which loads its javascript files.

Now, OAuth2 states that access tokens should be short-lived and refresh-token should be long-lived: in the *frontend* server logic, the API calls which receives a 401 (caused by the expired access token) are retried by sending first the refresh token to obtain a new access token via a Refresh Token Grant. If this second call is rejected, I assume the user is no more logged in (refresh token expired / revoked).

The pages are using Angular to perform data and ux/ui management. My question is:

**should the Angular code call directly the *API* server?**

Actually the first thing my javascript code does is to get a config object from the *frontend* server, which contains the access token too, and uses it to make the calls to the *API* server. The problem with this is that i should rewrite again the "refresh token logic" in javascript (after it expires, i get 401s), and by what I have read on the subject i understood that it is better to not make the refresh token visible to the client (as it can generate new access tokens).

So i was thinking about a "two step approach", where every javascript API call goes to an endpoint on the *frontend* server which relays it to the *API* server, but this is obviously slower (JS -> FRONTEND -> API and API -> FRONTEND -> JS).

What is the correct approach? It's not very clear to me if the frontend should be considered as *two clients* (php + js) which should work separately or not, as I imagine that an hypothetical iOS app would be making calls 100% against the *API* server.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the same approach in my own projects. The problem that we have is that the client is not secure. In order to generate / refresh a token, you need to pass secure information to the authorization server.

I have done the same as you basically, let the back-end handle the tokens and their temporary storage. You cannot and should not trust the client with important information which lets you generate tokens. In terms of delays, I wouldn't worry about it too much since you're not going to be doing that much extra work, you won't even notice the delays. I have a system like this built and used by hundreds of thousands of users with absolutely no issues.

Now, you have said a few things in here which make me wonder what you are doing.

OAuth2 is not a user authentication system, it's an application authentication system. You don't pass a user and their password and generate a token for them, you pass a ClientID and ClientSecret and they generate a token for you. Then you have an endpoint which gives you the user details for this user, you pass your userid or username and get the details of that user.

A token expired does not mean your user is logged out. Those are two completely different things. How are you going to expire a token for example, when your user wants to log out? You can't, your token will still be valid until it expires after the set amount of time has passed.

A token can be used for let's say half an hour, but your user may use the website for 1 hour. So before you hit any API endpoint, you could check ... has this token expired yet? if yes then you can go and refresh it and keep working without having to bother your user with a new login screen.

The whole point of an OAuth2 system is to make sure that only authorised clients can access it. A client is not a user, it's an application. You can have a  website for example and you only want users of that website to access your API.

You can have endpoints like ValidateUser for example, where you take a username and a password and return a yes or no and then you log your user in based on that.

Comment: You can use user/pass authentication, like you can see it here in the [Password Credential Grant](https://oauth2.thephpleague.com/authorization-server/resource-owner-password-credentials-grant/). On the API side i am validating the token first, then on the frontend side i am "logging in" the related user. If the user logs out, i "forget" its token by removing it from session... but you're right, that token can still be used. I'll revoke it from the API whilst removing it from session.

Comment: But if I understood correctly OAuth2 makes the client work on _behalf_ of the user, so can't it be strictly related?

Answer (score 0):

Irrespective of language/framework, second approach is secure and better than first one because to get access token by providing refresh token to Authorization server, it still requires Client ID and Secret which should never be passed to Browser for security reasons.

In first approach, to make a direct call it will not work if your Authz Server is hosted on different domain than your frontend server because of Same Origin policy of browsers. Even if they are on same domain, still you are exposing Client ID and Secret which will compromise your frontend server